# Having Trouble converting string to camel case

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I´ve been trying to figure out how to satisfy some conditions for a tutorial I am doing.

I have the following test spec to work from:

```
describe "String" do
  describe "camel_case" do
    it "leaves first word lowercase" do
      "test".camel_case.should eq("test")
    end
    it "should lowercase first letter if it isn't" do
      "Test".camel_case.should eq("test")
    end
    it "should combine words using camel case" do
      "This is a test".camel_case.should eq("thisIsATest")
    end
    it "should downcase words with capitals" do
      "MUST dOWNCASE words".camel_case.should eq("mustDowncaseWords")
    end
  end
end
```

I have managed to get the first two conditions working with the code below, but I have tried a bunch of different things to get the join and downcast with capitals conditions to work without success.

```
class String
  def camel_case
    self.downcase 
  end
end
```

I had been thinking that using a .split then .join method would work, but it does not.

Comment: Could you add your ".split then .join method"?

Comment: Can't you use [camelize](http://www.apidock.com/rails/String/camelize)

Comment: use split to give yourself an array of the words then probably each with index to manipulate each word individually over the array? the point of each with index being that you can identify the first word (so as not to upcase its first letter)... alternatively use map to upcase the first letter of each word in the array then use join then downcase the very first letter...

Comment: array = split(' ').map(&:capitalize) gives you an array of words, then array[0].downcase! and then join them!

You may want to test that the original string wasn't an empty field else you'll get a NoMethodError or two.

Comment: As @Baloo recommended, use [camelize](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html), which is part of ActiveSupport's string inflections module. It's been battle-tested.

Comment: .split(" ").map(&:capitalize).join().tap {|a| a[0] = a[0].chr.downcase} ... ruby is madness

Comment: I wanted to use camelize, but for some reason I couldn't get it to fire in my code.

self.camelize(:lower) was what I tried originally. Which looked correct based on the documentation. 

Thanks for all the answers here guys! I hope to be able to contribute one day - for now, I'll have to be content with leeching a little instead.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you actually do not do any camelizing. The only thing your `camel_case` method does is makes all the letters of the phrase... eh... down-cased.
`split` and `join` afterwards are the right things to do though.

```
class String
  def camel_case
    downcased = self.downcase # here you only downcased your input
    array_of_words = downcased.split
    # now you should make the first letter of each word upper-cased
    # ...
    words_with_first_letter_capitalized.join
  end
end
```

Comment: don't forget to downcase the first letter after the join or else it WillBeLikeThis insteadOfLikeThis...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of downcase use camelize or camelcase.